Showing a limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{n}{2} e^{-n\left|t \right|} f(t) \, dt = 2$
$f(t)$ is bounded and piecewise continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{t \to 0^-}f(t)=1$, $\lim_{t \to 0^+}f(t)=3$.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{n}{2} e^{-n\left|t \right|} f(t) \, dt = 2$$
My attempt:
First note from boundedness $\exists M\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(t) \le M\quad \forall t\in\mathbb{R}$.
By a quick check we see that $\frac{n}{2}e^{-n\left|t \right|}=K_n(t)$ a positive summation kernel. So we strive to show the following:
$$\left|  \int_{\mathbb{R}}K_n(t)f(t)\,dt - 2 \right|  = \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} (f(t)-2)K_n(t)\,dt\right| \le \int_{-\delta}^{\delta}\left|f(t)-2 \right|K_n(t)\,dt + \int_{\delta<\left|t\right|}\left|f(t)-2 \right|K_n(t)dt$$
Using the fact that for $n>N$ large enough the second integral is goes to zero more precisely:
$$\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}\left|f(t)-2 \right|K_n(t)\,dt + \int_{\delta<\left|t\right|}2MK_n(t)\,dt \le \int_{-\delta}^{\delta}\left|f(t)-2 \right|K_n(t)\,dt + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$.
Now I am at a loss, not sure what I should do with a first integral as it is discontinuous at $t=0$ any hints how I should work with this? Thank you!!

@SineoftheTime this is from a graduate book for Fourier analysis, I was not sure if to add it but I figured it wouldn't hurt.

are you allowed to use the dominated convergence theorem?

@SineoftheTime I don't think so, since I haven't heard of it yet

This question is essentially à duplicate of Help with a limit of an integral: $\lim_{h\to \infty}h\int_{0}^\infty{{ {e}^{-hx}f(x)} dx}=f(0)$, which shows that in your case, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty ne^{-nt}f(t)dt=1$. Similarly,
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^0 ne^{nt}f(t)dt=3.$

From boundedness, let $ M\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $
\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\quad
|f(t)|\le M$.
Given $\epsilon>0$, fix some $\delta>0$ such that $\forall t\in(0,\delta)\quad|f(t)-1|<\epsilon$. Then,
$$\left|\int_0^\infty ne^{-nt}f(t)dt-1\right|\le
\int_0^\infty ne^{-nt}|f(t)-1|dt
\le\epsilon(1-e^{-n\delta})+(M+1)e^{-n\delta}\le2\epsilon$$ for all $n$ large enough. So, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty ne^{-nt}f(t)dt=1.$$
Similarly,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^0 ne^{nt}f(t)dt=3.$$

ah I see! I was hoping writing it as PSK would make it easier but apparently, that's where I missed out! Thank you!

Well, you can, if you replace everywhere in your approach $f(t)$ by $\frac{f(t)+f(-t)}2$. Since $K_n$ is even, this doesn't change $\int_{\mathbb{R}}K_n(t)f(t),dt$.

I will try this too! Thanks!

Brief comment. The test-function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{-x^2} & x<0,\\
3e^{-x^2} & x>0.
\end{cases} $$
satisfies your assumptions, and the integral against $\mathbb R\ni x\mapsto \frac n2 e^{-nx}$ makes sense for all $n$. Let us evaluate it. Note that, through a change of variables, one computes
$$\int_\mathbb R \frac n2 e^{-nx}\,e^{-x^2}\,dx =  \frac{n\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{n^2/4}, $$
so that, by symmetry,
$$\int_\mathbb R \frac n2 e^{-nx}\,f(x)\,dx =  \left(\frac{n\sqrt{\pi}}{4}+\frac{3n\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\right)e^{n^2/4} = n\sqrt{\pi}\,e^{n^2/4}.$$
The right-hand side blows up as $n\to\infty$, so the statement without an absolute value symbol in the exponent is false.

Consider then $K_n(x) = \frac n 2 e^{-n|x|}$ and suppose $f$ satisfies your assumptions. Note that
$$\int_\mathbb R K_n(x)\,f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\frac 1 {\sqrt n}}^{\frac 1 {\sqrt n}} \frac n 2 e^{n|x|}\,f(x)\,dx + \int_{\mathbb R\setminus \left [-\frac 1 {\sqrt n},\frac 1 {\sqrt n}\right]} \frac n 2e^{n|x|}\,f(x)\,dx. $$
The second integral on the right-hand side can be estimated as follows:
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb R\setminus [-1/\sqrt n,+1/\sqrt n]} \frac n 2e^{n|x|}\,f(x)\,dx\right|\leqslant \int_{\mathbb R\setminus \left[-\frac 1 {\sqrt n},\frac 1 {\sqrt n}\right]} \frac n 2e^{n|x|}\,|f(x)|\,dx \leqslant M\,e^{-\sqrt n} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0.$$
Therefore, we are done if we show that the other integral converges to $2$. Note that $f$ is piecewise continuous: hence, there exists $\bar n$ large enough such that $f$ is continuous on both $\left(0,\frac 1 {\sqrt{\bar n}}\right]$ and $\left[-\frac 1 {\sqrt{\bar n}},0\right)$. We shall always assume $n\geqslant\bar n$ henceforth. By substitution,
$$I^+_n:=\int_0^{\frac 1 {\sqrt{n}}} \frac n 2 e^{-nx}\,f(x)\,dx = \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\sqrt n} f\left(\frac u n\right)e^{-u}du.$$
Now, since $u \in [0,\sqrt n]$ entails $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(u/n) = 3$, the sequence of functions $(f^+_n)$ defined by
$$f_n^+(u) := \frac 1 2\,e^{-u}\,f\left(\frac u n\right)\,\mathbf{1}_{[0,\sqrt n]}(u) $$
converges uniformly to $f^+$ given by $f^+(u) := \frac 3 2\,e^{-u}\,\mathbf{1}_{[0,+\infty)}(u)$. (Can you show this?)
We deduce
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} I^+_n = \int_\mathbb R \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n^+\right)(u)\,du = \frac 3 2 \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-u} du = \frac 3 2\,.$$
Similarly,
$$I_n^- := \int^0_{-\frac 1 {\sqrt{n}}} \frac n 2 e^{nx}\,f(x)\,dx = \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\sqrt n} f\left(-\frac u n\right)e^{-u}du\,,$$
and the sequence $(f^-_n)$ defined by
$$f^-_n(u) := \frac 1 2\,e^{-u}\,f\left(-\frac u n\right)\,\mathbf{1}_{[0,\sqrt n]}(u) $$ converges uniformly to $f^-$ such that $f^-(u) := \frac 1 2\,e^{-u}\,\mathbf{1}_{[0,+\infty)}(u)$, so that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} I^-_n = \int_\mathbb R \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n^-\right)(u)\,du = \frac 1 2 \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-u} du = \frac 1 2\,.$$
Therefore,
$$\int_{-\frac 1 {\sqrt{n}}}^{\frac 1 {\sqrt{n}}} \frac n 2 e^{-n|x|}\,f(x)\,dx = I_n^+ + I_n^- \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \frac 3 2 + \frac 1 2 = 2. $$
